# Equality holds for all $A\in\mathcal{F}_n$ for all $n$ implies equality for all $A\in\mathcal{F}_\infty$ (Chung Thm 9.4.8.)

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Theorem 9.4.8: Suppose $Y$ is an integrable random variable. Then $\lim_n E(Y|\mathcal{F}_n)=E(Y|\mathcal{F}_\infty)$.

Proof: Define $X_n=E(Y|\mathcal{F}_n)$. Observe that $\{X_n,\mathcal{F}_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a uniformly integrable martingale, so $X_n$ converges a.e. to an integrable $X_\infty$ so that $\{X_n,\mathcal{F}_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}_\infty}$ is a martingale (Chung Theorem 9.4.6). Note that for all $n$ and $A\in\mathcal{F}_n$,

$$\int_A Y=\int_A X_n=\int_A X_\infty,$$
with first equality by definition of conditional expectation, and the second by noting that uniform integrability gives $L^1$ convergence (Chung Theorem 9.4.5).

Fine so far. The claim is proved if we can say that the above equalities hold for all $A\in\mathcal{F}_\infty$. If $A\in\mathcal{F}_n$ for some $n$, we are done. But I was informed in my previous question that this may not be so, and I'm not sure how to proceed.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a random variable $X$ denote by $X^+$ and $X^-$ its positive part and negative part, respectively. Clearly,

$$\int_A Y = \int_A X_{\infty}$$

implies

$$\nu(A) := \int_A (Y^+ +X^-_{\infty}) = \int_A (X^+_{\infty}+Y^-) =: \mu(A)$$

for all $G \in \mathcal{G} := \bigcup_{n \geq 1} \mathcal{F}_n$. Note that $\mathcal{G}$ is a $\cap$-stable generator of $\mathcal{F}_{\infty} = \sigma(\mathcal{F}_n; n \geq 1)$. The (finite) measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ coincide on $\mathcal{G}$, and therefore a standard result from measure theory (see below) tells us that

$$\mu(A) = \nu(A) \qquad \text{for all $A \in \mathcal{F}_{\infty}$}.$$

By the very definition of $\mu$ and $\nu$ this is equivalent to

$$\int_A Y = \int_A X_{\infty}\qquad \text{for all $A \in \mathcal{F}_{\infty}$}.$$

> **(Uniqueness of measures theorem)** Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ be two finite measures on a measurable space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A})$. If $\mathcal{G}$ is a $\cap$-stable generator of $\mathcal{A}$ and $$\mu(G) = \nu(G) \qquad \text{for all} \, \, G \in \mathcal{G} \cup \{\Omega\}$$ then $$\mu(A) = \mu(A) \qquad \text{for all $A \in \mathcal{A}.$}$$

(There are more general versions of this result.) For a proof see e.g. *Measures, integrals and martingales* by René Schilling. One possible approach to prove the statement is to show that

$$\mathcal{D} := \{A \in \mathcal{A}; \mu(A) = \nu(A)\}$$

is a Dynkin system; as $\mathcal{G} \subseteq \mathcal{A}$ this implies that the smallest Dynkin system containing $\mathcal{G}$ is contained in $\mathcal{D}$. Finally, since $\mathcal{G}$ is $\cap$-stable, the smallest Dynkin system containing $\mathcal{G}$ equals the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathcal{G}$, and this finishes the proof.

Comment: Maybe it would be helpful to cite the "standard result" - it is most likely proved using the $\pi$-$\lambda$ or monotone class theorems, and I think you could also invoke those results directly without introducing the measures $\mu,\nu$.  In fact, a lot of books would abbreviate this whole discussion by saying "by a monotone class argument".

Comment: @NateEldredge Well, yeah, sure there are other ways to prove the result. I usually try to avoid the monotone class theorem since, in my experience, a lot of students are rather uncomortable with it. (I have added the statement of the "standard result".)

Comment: Thanks, that's nice.  I agree it's really a matter of taste.  I have written out the monotone class argument in another answer; maybe this particular student will become less uncomfortable :-)

Comment: @NateEldredge Let's hope so. :)

Comment: @NateEldredge Thank you both for the excellent responses. I will admit to having avoided reading about monotone class theorems, but I imagine if they keep popping up I will eventually convince myself I'm better off familiarizing myself

Comment: @manofbear: Yes, I'd say the sooner the better.  It's an essential technical tool in probability theory as well as analysis, and underlies many of the "density arguments" that are so common.  It's a little strange to work with at first, but you'll get more comfortable quickly if you work through some examples.

Answer (score 2):

This is a "monotone class argument".  See Chung's Theorem 2.1.2.

Let $\mathcal{G}_0 = \bigcup_n \mathcal{F}_n$.  You can verify that $\mathcal{G}_0$ is a field (but not a $\sigma$-field, or "BF" in Chung's language).  By definition, $\mathcal{F}_\infty = \sigma(\mathcal{G}_0)$ (the "minimal BF" containing $\mathcal{G}_0$).

Let $\mathcal{G} = \{A \subset \mathcal{F}_\infty : \int_A Y = \int_A X_\infty\}$.  What you have previously shown is that $\mathcal{G}_0 \subset \mathcal{G}$.  Now you can show that $\mathcal{G}$ is a monotone class: if $A_n$ is an increasing (resp., decreasing) sequence in $\mathcal{G}$, then $\bigcup_n A_n$ (resp. $\bigcap_n A_n$) is in $\mathcal{G}$.  Once you unpack the notation, this is just an application of the dominated convergence theorem.

So the monotone class theorem says $\mathcal{G} = \mathcal{F}_\infty$.  That is, $\int_A Y = \int_A X_\infty$ for all $A \in \mathcal{F}_\infty$.  Now taking $A = \{Y > X_\infty\}$ and $\{Y < X_\infty\}$ (which are in $\mathcal{F}_\infty$ since $Y, X_\infty$ are both $\mathcal{F}_\infty$-measurable) you get $Y \le X_\infty$ and $Y \ge X_\infty$ almost surely.